# embed code loop not working

Tags: html, loops, embed

```
<embed 
    id="audio_1" 
    src="website.com/music.mp3"  
    loop=TRUE 
    autoplay="true" 
    PLAYCOUNT="3">
```

This `embed` code loop isn't working. I tried using `loop` and `playcount` but none of the attributes are working for me, `autoplay` is working fine though. This doesn't works in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: you need `""` quotes around TRUE

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out: you need to have playlist="" to use loop

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/peSfCy7HFrM?playlist=peSfCy7HFrM&loop=1;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set `autostart = true` also for it.
`Loop` is supported by Netscape only.You can also try `LOOP = 3` then it will run 3 times.

thanks

Comment: How can do it for other browser , atleast for chrome/firefox